# Youtube-dl isn't ignoring unavailable videos

Tags: youtube-dl

I tried to download a full playlist with youtube-dl but after downloading 31 videos it stopped. I tried -i but it won't ignore or skip.

I tried: `youtube-dl -f 136+251 -i "Playlist_Link"`

I installed youtube-dl with pip3 and I'm using version 2020.11.18 (latest).

Here is an image with the error message:

[image]

Comment: `-i` should continue on download errors and I don't know why it's not, but the error you're facing is not about unavailable videos on the playlist, it's because you're asking for a format that is not available.

Comment: Yeah I know that but it should skip when I use -i or --ignore .right ??? Need a solution quick @SMMousaviSP

Comment: If you look at the man page, it says `-i` will ignore downloading errors; maybe it doesn't recognize the error you're facing as a downloading error. I have two suggestions for you:
1. Get the URL of the videos you want to download and add `youtube-dl -f 136+251` at the beginning of each line, save it as a .sh file and run that file, this way, if youtube-dl fail to download one file, it doesn't stop downloading the others.
2. Open an issue for the problem you're facing in the youtube-dl repo on GitHub, and wait for them to fix this: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl